# When i install my flutter app on Android devices, the onBackgroundMessage() doesn't work. Someone knows how to solve?

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using onBackgroundMessage() and FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen() to receive notifications both in Background and Foreground mode, but i only get the notifications in Foreground. Here's a snippet of my app.dart:

`import 'package:souhi/services/firebase_messaging.service.dart';`

`import 'package:souhi/services/notification.service.dart';`

`class App extends StatefulWidget {`
`const App({`

````
```super.key,
````

});

`@override`

`State<App> createState() =>`
`_AppState();`
`}`

`class _AppState extends State<App> {`
`bool isAlertOnDialogOpen = false;`
`@override`
`void initState() {`
super.initState();

```
initializeFirebaseMessaging();
checkNotifications();

Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((event) async {
  await showConnectivityMessage(event);
});
```

}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {

```
 ...//skipping this part
```

}

initializeFirebaseMessaging() async {

```
await Provider.of<FirebaseMessagingService>(context, listen: false)
    .initialize();
```

}

checkNotifications() async {

```
await Provider.of<NotificationService>(context, listen: false)
    .checkForNotifications();
```

}

}```

My App.dart uses 2 services: FirebaseMessagingService and NotificationService. See that on FirebaseMessagingService i got thoses calls:

`Future<void> _onBackgroundMessage(RemoteMessage message) async {`

```
print('_onBackgroundMessage');
```

````
//   name: 'Monitorer',
//   options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
// );
notificationService.showNotification(message);```
}

class FirebaseMessagingService {


final NotificationService _notificationService;

FirebaseMessagingService(this._notificationService) {

  notificationService = _notificationService;
}

Future<void> initialize() async {

  print('firebase_messaging initialize');

  await FirebaseMessaging.instance
      .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
    alert: true,
  );
  var app = await Firebase.initializeApp(
    name: 'Monitorer',
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  onBackgroundMessage();
  _onMessage();

  
}


_onMessage() async {
  print('firebase_messaging _onMessage');

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {

    print('firebase_messaging onMessage listen');

    _notificationService.showNotification(message);
  });
}

onBackgroundMessage() {

  print('firebase_messaging _onBackgroundMessage');
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_onBackgroundMessage);
}```



I've tried so many things. I'm using all the permissions in my AndroidManifest.xml and even this way, it didn't work out: 

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />    
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
````

Comment: Please explain your question in a simpler manner.

Comment: Hi @BaimamBoukar . Excuse me.What i wanna know is: How can i get notification in background mode ?